# Css - Why do my inputs get full width?

Tags: asp.net, css

The page is from an ASP.NET project. The idea is that every button is contained within a  that gets 25% of its parent's width. The button then gets 100% of the td's width. This is supposed to create buttons that are always of the same size.

However, as you can see in the jsfiddle link below, even if there's only one button, it gets the full table width. Why is this, when the td has 25% width?

```
<table style="width: 90%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="">
            <td class="speed-agenda-button-container">
                <input type="button" class="speed-agenda-button"                         onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl50','')" value="A lonely button" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl50">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


.speed-agenda-button-container {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  width: 25%;
}

.speed-agenda-button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: medium none;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tA5vu/1/

Bonus question: In Firefox, the button heights look alright, while in Chrome they get awfully high. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, tables have a width of 90%, cells fill this width. As you have a table of only one cell, although it is set to 25% this would leave unallocated table space, so instead it takes the table width of 90%.

You will need to set the table width to 25% if you are only using one cell (which begs the question, why are you using a table?)

It seems like the most effective solution is to move the 25% width from the table cell class to the button class.

To ensure the 25% includes any padding etc, set `box-sizing:border-box` on the button css as well as `display:block` and `float:left`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/tA5vu/8/)

Regarding button height, this is being derived from your large `line-height` value, simply reduce this as appropriate.

Comment: I am using a table because it gets created dynamically and has anywhere between 1 and 4 buttons.

Thanks for pointing out the line-height. That was an oversight of mine!

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson - check the revised demo fiddle above, does it work for you?

Comment: It doesn't quite work for the cases when I have 2-4 buttons. Every button needs to fill their 25% (minus padding)

Comment: That is good. But it displays on two rows for me (unless I downsize width to 23%)

Comment: Hmmm, now there's no padding between the buttons. Maybe I should just keep the previous one, and then keep things at 23%?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson - set margins, then use `calc` for the width: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/tA5vu/9/

Comment: God damnit, when I use this in my project, the first button on a row looks allright, but the rest become very small as such: http://i.imgur.com/qhIOfEZ.png and also, the first button on different rows don't become equally big either :(

Answer (score 1):

```
.speed-agenda-button-container 
{
  background-clip: padding-box;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  width: 25%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
```

Change the style like this. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tA5vu/5/)

Comment: The problem with this is you're taking a DOM `td` element within a table and telling it to not behave like a cell, but as another table. Semantically this isnt great, or an intended implementation of `display:table`

Comment: When I do this and add another button, it stacks them vertically.

Comment: This is starting to look very good, thanks. But for four buttons, I need to change the container width somewhat, down to 23%, in order to have it display on one row. Is this because of padding?